# plantuml - better disposition of arrows and text

Tags: graph, uml, plantuml, component-diagram

I'm trying to plot this component diagram with plantuml

```
@startuml
skinparam linetype ortho
left to right direction

folder BASE {
    folder foo {
        component aaa
    }
    folder bar {
        component bbb
        folder ENV {
              artifact ccc <<config>>
              artifact ddd <<db>>
        }
    }

}

folder lorem {
    folder ipsum {
        component eee
        component fff
        component ggg
    }
    folder amet {
        component panel <<jar>>
    }
    folder dolor {
        artifact hhh <<config>>
    }
}

folder fox {
    folder jumps {
    artifact jjj <<document>>
    artifact kkk <<document>>
    artifact mmm<<document>>

    }
    folder lazy {
        artifact context.txt
    }
}

aaa --> context.txt : write
aaa --> bbb : launch
bbb --> hhh : read
bbb --> panel : launch
panel --> ccc : read
panel --> ddd : read

panel --> eee : run
panel --> fff : run
panel --> ggg : run

panel --> kkk : write
eee --> jjj : read
eee --> mmm: write

ggg --> jjj : write
ggg --> mmm: read

@enduml
```

the result is a bit messy: arrows overlapping and text on arrows difficult to read

see
[image]

Is there a way to better control arrows and text disposition?
(for example something for minimizing arrow intersections and having text closer to the corresponding arrow)

Answer (score 2):

When a diagram is complex, it can be a nondeterministic struggle to make it more readable. Some suggestions:

- make the associations wider with `skinparam ArrowThickness 3` or change the font for the text on the arrows to bold in a similar way.
- try `skinparam linetype polyline`
- put the names at the start or the end of an arrow, e.g. instead of `panel --> eee : run` use `panel "run" --> eee` (for the name at the start) or `panel --> "run" eee` (for the name at the end)
- group two packages inside a `together {...}` (it's like a hidden rectangle, and will perhaps add more space).
- toggle the `left to right direction` instruction (with a comment).

Here are a few of things applied to your diagram, but it could be better:

```
@startuml
skinparam linetype polyline
'left to right direction

skinparam Arrow {
    MessageAlignment left
    Thickness 3
    FontStyle Bold
    Color Blue
}

folder BASE {
    folder foo {
        component aaa
    }
    folder bar {
        component bbb
        folder ENV {
              artifact ccc <<config>>
              artifact ddd <<db>>
        }
    }

}

folder lorem {
    folder ipsum {
        component eee
        component fff
        component ggg
    }
    folder amet {
        component panel <<jar>>
    }
    folder dolor {
        artifact hhh <<config>>
    }
}

folder fox {
    folder jumps {
    artifact jjj <<document>>
    artifact kkk <<document>>
    artifact mmm<<document>>

    }
    folder lazy {
        artifact context.txt
    }
}

aaa --> "write" context.txt
aaa --> "launch" bbb 
bbb --> "read" hhh
bbb --> panel : launch
panel --> ccc : read
panel --> ddd : read

panel --> eee : run
panel --> fff : run
panel --> ggg : run

panel --> kkk : write
eee --> jjj : read
eee --> mmm: write

ggg --> jjj : write
ggg --> mmm: read
@enduml
```

[image: Polyline and other hacks]